# the centraliser of a 2x2 matrix can only have dimension 2 or 4

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove whether this is true or false. I believe it to be true as I cannot find any counter examples but I'm struggling to back it up in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tedious but I'd calculate out $AX = XA$ where

$$A =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a_1 & a_2 \\
a_3 & a_4 \end{array} \right)$$

and

$$X =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x_1 & x_2 \\
x_3 & x_4 \end{array} \right).$$

$A$ is the known matrix whose centralizer you are trying to find and $X$ represents an element of the centralizer.  Computing $AX - XA$ will give you four equations.  Move the elements in these equations around so that they are all in the form

$$a'_1x_1 + a'_2x_2+a'_3x_3 + a'_4x_4 = 0.$$

The $a'_i$ values will be some addition or subtraction of your original $a$ values.  For instance it may be that $a'_2 = a_4 - a_1$.

Once you have this you can use Gaussian elimination to solve for your $x$ values.  Be careful when dividing however.  You are inherently assuming the denominator is non-zero.